# Deployer - Fatal error: Call to undefined function server()

Tags: php, php-deployer

> Deployer version 4.1.0

When running `dep deploy test` the following error is reported:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function server()

server ftn is defined as follows in config file:

```
// Configure servers
server('test', 'test.server.com')
    ->user('user')
    ->identityFile('~/.ssh/id.pub', '~/.ssh/user', 'password')
    ->stage("test")
    ->env('deploy_path', '/var/www/project.com');
```

This is pretty much the standard as per the [Deployer site](https://deployer.org/docs/servers). Has anyone else experienced this issue? If so how did you resolve it?

Comment: Did you make sure deployer is setup correctly on your machine ? [Does their intro work?](https://deployer.org/docs/getting-started)

Comment: The error clearly states `server()` isn't defined. If you're using a definition in another file, make sure that file is properly included

Comment: I was using a previously deploy config file. I'm going to rename it and try the intro.

Comment: Please do not add the solution to the question. Instead, add the solution as an answer, then self-accept.

Comment: @bishop done. I will remove this comment later

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Fixed issue by running the following cmd (Suggested in comments above by Ken)

> dep init

Compared the auto-generated deploy.php file to the original. Noted that the following was omitted:

```
namespace Deployer;
```

Also noted that `->env` has been replaced with `->set`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using deployer on a Laravel 5.4 project:

I had installed deployer using composer, when removed it and worked with `deployer.phar`file , everything worked fine.